# How to auto insert text in an html form and auto submit it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a project, what i simply want to do is create an html form for posting reply but if the user is too lazy to reply he/she can just click auto-generate comment and a text is directly inserted on the form and automatically posted afterwards..

Comment: Have you tried anything before asking question?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code of what you tried

Comment: You also can use Microsoft Outlook Reply with Template Add-in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$( "#lazybutton" ).click(function() {
  $('#inputBox').val("Hey I feel too lazy to type"); // filled automatically in input box        
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#form').submit(); //submitting form
    }, 2000);
});
```

added sleep time so users can see input box for 2 sec after filled it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to execute at client site.

create a Array/String of predefined answer and create a click handler of Posting button then insert predefined answer to comment box and post it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var RandComment= ["First Random Comment","Second Random Comment","Third Random Comment"]
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        var pickRandomComment = RandComment[parseInt(Math.random() * RandComment.length-1)];
        $("#txtCommentBox").val(pickRandomComment);        
        //Call ajax if want to implement

    });
});
```

Comment: That is not an answer. It is more of a comment. Please add the code needed to perform your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

For this, first, you should generate the text and append the generated text to comment field. But after I'm not sure what do you want as asking for "automatically posted". Do you want to post the form as like normally pressing the submit button? If yes, you may use the below code as logic.

```
$("button#lazyGenerate").on("click", function(){
  var generatedText = "bla bla and bla";
  $("#yourCommentField").val(generatedText);

$("input[name='submitButtonName']").click();

});
```

Comment: Why the need for AJAX? If the form is submitted it will perform a post

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, the input can be populated using `.val()` then submitting the form using `.submit()` which will be the same as the submit button being clicked.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#autogen', function(){
  $('#myTextarea').val('Some comment here');
  $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" action="/" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="myTextarea" name="myTextarea">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<button id="autogen">Generate</button>
```

Reference: [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: That is true. The post was tagged with 'jQuery' so gave a jQuery answer.